# Is there a java sister to ruby Omniauth library from Intridea?

Tags: java, ruby, jetty, omniauth

Ideally for Jetty. Ideally working with Facebook.

[Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) is a standardized multi-provider authentication.